# "For" loop output issue in R

Tags: r, loops

I am struggling with an output allocation issue in a "for" loop: I generate an empty matrix ("results") with appropriate (is it not???) dimensions where the loop should allocate the output from the function (pls), but I am getting an error... Here is the code:

```
library(pls)
set.seed(10000)
mat <- replicate(100, rnorm(100))
y <- as.matrix(mat[,1], drop=F)
x <- mat[,2:100]
min.nc <- 3
max.nc <- 8
nc <- seq(min.nc, max.nc)
results <- matrix(NA, length(nc), 1)
for(q in nc) {
  pls <- plsr(y ~ x, ncomp = q)
  results[q,] <- RMSEP(pls, intercept=F, estimate="train")$val[1,1,q]
}
```

The error message after running the "for" loop says:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, q, , value = 0.329631604369802) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

...which I don't understand, since the iterator "nc" has exactly the size of "length(nc)". Any ideas?

Many thanks for your time and help!

Chega

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `q` is 3:8 and your matrix `results` is 1:6.  Thus, when it tries to assign `results[q,]` when `q > 6` you get this error.

```
> results[7,]
Error in results[7, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

The value of `q` is each value of `nc` rather than `seq_along(nc)`.

```
for (q in nc) print(q)
```

Versus

```
for (q in seq_along(nc)) print(nc[q])
```

Comment: So seq_along() is the tool I was obviously missing! Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The naive method would be `1:length(nc)` but this will fail in surprising ways if `nc` is length 0 or doesn't exist.

Comment: I see - I can use seq_along() and seq_len() in most cases when 1:length() seems handy...